# How can I make a button on tkinter run a function that loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tkinter

I have a specific problem here: I have a button which, when pressed, runs a function that basically consists of a loop.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

def loop():
    while True:

        print("loop") 

b = Button (root, text = "run", command = loop)
b.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

The loop, of course, runs fine. However, as soon as it starts running, the program cannot continue and execute `mainloop()` again. This means the tkinter window becomes unresponsive. In my actual program, this prevents me from being able to exit the loop and change the function.

So, how can I change the code to make the tkinter window responsive again?

Comment: The program isn't responding because it's handling the loop, which goes on forever. You could multithread your program or get rid of the infinite loop. The program will resume once the loop completes

Comment: look at `after()` it is specifically meant to handle this kind of looping to avoid the use of `while` so you don't block the mainloop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tkinter method called `after()` is what you want to use here.

Here is an example of it in action and I have changed the button to toggle a tracking variable to simulate starting and stopping the loop.

The below code will first check if the loop is being accessed by the button and then toggle on or off basically. Then there is a loop built in with the `after` method to continue the loop until you press the button again.

```
import tkinter as tk


def loop(toggle=False):
    global tracking_var
    if toggle:
        if tracking_var:
            tracking_var = False
        else:
            tracking_var = True

    if tracking_var:
        print("loop")
        root.after(1000, loop)

root = tk.Tk()
tracking_var = False
tk.Button(root, text="run", command=lambda: loop(True)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you show an similar example with a while loop? My program relies on while loops, and I'm struggling to adapt this to a while loop. Thanks

Comment: @J.Barker you cannot use while loops with tkinter without using threading. I am not sure what  kind of example you would want. Threading may be overkill for what you need and the after statement works fine. What part is it you are having a hard time with?

Comment: It’s ok, I’ll try and adapt the code using the after function (I think I understand how to do it now). I’ve tried threading, and it’s a bit too much of a pain to do. Thanks anyway